# I want to update apache 2.4.7 to 2.4.25, will it destroy my current configuration?

Tags: apache2

So, I wanted to upgrade my apache (on ubuntu 14.04) and enable `http/2` doing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Will it have any affect to my current configuration, I mean my conf files, modules, virutal hosts etc.?

Anyone tried this?

Comment: Do a backup, or try first on virtual  machine

Comment: I just did a test in my VM and it didn't destroy nothing, meanwhile in the middle of installation it will prompt a message if you want to install new configuration files or to keep old config files.

Comment: But yeah, backup should be there in case if something will go wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do:

- First step: Do a backup.
- Second step: Test in virtual machine
- Third step: Upgrade and select keep your old data
- Fourth step: Test apache.
- Firfth step : Resotore the backup if the upgrading failed

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had modified one of the system configs so apt-get asked me if I want to keep my changes or not. I chose to see the differences and it was 1 modified line.